# Deployed Google Action (production release) cannot be found on Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I deployed the production release for my first Google Action. But even 2 weeks after the approved deployment I can find my action neither in the Google Assistant store nor directly via voice activation.

The test versions ran fine and was found every single time. So the invocation name should not be the problem. When I use the generated action link from the console I find the action in the store and can send it to my Smartphone, where I can start it with the sent link. But after closing the app I cannot open it again via voice.

I used two different google accounts on different devices (all are set up in the right language: german), but no chance.

Is this a mistake on Googles side or do I miss anything? In this state I have to open the action every time over the action link which is useless for a voice app :)

---

Here is the link to my action: https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/000000c77f740137?hl=de

The invocation would be for example: "Mit Erfolgs-Fans sprechen" (like said, on the test this name was found every single time)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. Though it wasn't in production when I faced it. I was also not able to see the action in Assistant-enabled devices (Google home app/assistant).

It is probably not the invocation name issue, it is just that the action is not being made visible across all the platforms. Some of the solutions I tried were-

1. Clean cache of the device
2. Create a new action with everything just the same as in your current actions. It worked once for me!
3. Go to GCP and under your project, try to understand if there is any pending activity.
4. Once I created so many actions because I wasn't able to see it that after around 30 days all those actions started to become visible. So, if you can wait that is fine.
5. In the end, do contact their [support](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) with all the relevant information. I hope they should be able to help.

Thank you!